# Domain transfer and New Hosting Management

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration

I wanted to migrate from my older registrar to GoDaddy. Main reason because current registrar/hosting provider doesn't support **.NET**.

My old registrar gave me control over the domain and hosting account. So, basically I have everything I would need. ( I know theory only )

I applied for Transfer of domain, bought a hosting package from GoDaddy and uploaded new web site.

So, I am waiting for domain transfer and it tells me that I have to wait for 5-7 days for approval. Okay.

But today, my old registrar told/taunted me that I really didn't need to apply for transfer. What could possibly I have done differently? My domain expires on this 15th.

Now I don't know much about how all of this really works, but I am guessing he meant, "***you should have waited for 15 days and let it expire after which you should buy the domain as it is expired***".

**Is it really so**(I doubt) or

**there are some other ways I could have got same result but without transferring domain**? (like, changing DNS entries)

I have read like all of the documentation available on namecheap/GoDaddy/Whois about domain transfers. But maybe because I am new to this it is all confusing to me.

I would also like to know what to do with DNS settings after transfer succeeds. I want to kill the old website. So, **what nameserver settings I need to change, new one or old one or both?**

I have **old host+old domain registrar + old working site** on one hand, on the other hand, **new site + pending domain transfer + new DNS settings**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off every domain has what is called a domain password or EPP. you will need to get this to transfer between registrars (assuming godaddy is a registrar.) In most cases you will need to put this in writing, and they will only email the registered domain email address. Start by looking around on your current providers' website, or call or email support.

Then you need to initiate a transfer of domain from your old registrar to the new one. Here in Australia, it takes around 48 hours, elsewhere up to 7 days.

Once the 2 companies have mucked about transferring it over, the new registrar will handle your domain requests. From here you are able to point your DNS settings to the new name servers (it can be done through your godaddy dashboard). This will take a little bit of time to update before people will be directed to your new site - anywhere up to 48 hours.

From there it is away you go.

If you do have trouble with your current/old provider not supplying you any of the information/handling your requests, you can file a complaint to internic via http://www.internic.net/

So for the tl;dr:
1) get epp
2) request transfer in writing with old hoster of domain name
3) wait for that to happen, then update dns on new domain registrar
4) in the meantime get your website ready on their test server (usually can test by typing an ip)
5) win.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Domains and hosting can be with different companies. To get the same result you can change the nameserver entries on your domain to point to the DNS servers on your hosting - even if it's with a different company.

However, now that a transfer is going ahead you don't need to do anything with the old website. Once the domain has been transferred, your DNS settings on the domain with the new company should point to your new hosting and your old hosting won't be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you dont need to transfer your domain. Please just point your domain to GoDaddy name server.